# inclusion in $L^{p}$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\sigma,\mu)$ be finite measure space then for $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$, prove the inclusion $L^{q}(X)\subseteq L^{p}(X)$ is strict.

I know example of this case when $X=[0,1]$, so I am also interested to know is there a way to embedd $L^{p}(X)$ of finite measure space $X$ to some other $L^{p}(Y)$ where $Y$ is well understood, for example $Y=[0,1]$ ?

Comment: The inclusion is not always strict. Eg. $X=\{0\}, \mu (X)=1, \mu (\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: What about when $X=\mathbb{T}^{2}$, a torus? Here $\mathbb{T}$ is a unit circle.